# Kubernetes install fails on ACS

Tags: azure, containers, kubernetes

I'm trying to deploy Kubernetes through ACS. The deployment works perfectly but as soon as I try connect to the cluster with kubectl proxy it fails.
Every kubectl command fails.

I SSH'ed to the server and found out only one container started. Not a single other one in sight even with -a.

Anyone got a clue to why this happens?

Comment: sometimes things like this happen, I would suggest reinstalling cluster from scratch.

Comment: I already tried this 3 times and every time it doesn't work.

Comment: how are you deploying that?

Comment: Through the Azure Portal with ACS. I create the service principal upfront through powershell

Comment: ARM template or just the new resource wizard? I've hardly seen it failing using the portal. And you say there are no errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, it seems you have **not** configured the Service Principal correctly.
You may need to check to ensure the credentials were provided accurately, and that **the configured Service Principal has read and write permissions to the target Subscription.**
If your Service Principal is misconfigured, none of the kubernetes components will come up in a healthy manner. We can check to see if this the problem:

```
root@k8s-master-D9DE702A-0:~# journalctl -u kubelet | grep --text autorest
```

If you see output that looks like the following, it means you have not configured the service Principal correctly.

```
May 18 07:09:36 k8s-master-D9DE702A-0 docker[5534]: E0518 07:09:36.901937    5920 kubelet.go:1186] Cannot get Node info: failed to get external ID from cloud provider: autorest#WithErrorUnlessStatusCode: POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/1fcf418e-66ed-4c99-9449-d8e18bf8737a/oauth2/token?api-version=1.0 failed with 400 Bad Request: StatusCode=400
May 18 07:09:37 k8s-master-D9DE702A-0 docker[5534]: E0518 07:09:37.119646    5920 kubelet_node_status.go:70] Unable to construct api.Node object for kubelet: failed to get external ID from cloud provider: autorest#WithErrorUnlessStatusCode: POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/1fcf418e-66ed-4c99-9449-d8e18bf8737a/oauth2/token?api-version=1.0 failed with 400 Bad Request: StatusCode=400
```

More information about how to create /configure a service principal for ACS-Engin Kubernetes cluster, please refer to this [Azure CLI 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-service/container-service-kubernetes-service-principal) or [PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-authenticate-service-principal).

We can use CLI 2.0 to get the information about ACS, the clientId is the service principal.

```
C:\Users>az acs show -g k8s -n containerservice-k8s
{
  "agentPoolProfiles": [
    {
.
.
.
.

  },
  "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
  "resourceGroup": "k8s",
  "servicePrincipalProfile": {
    "clientId": "1498b171-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-8ef56a178b89",
    "secret": null
  },
  "tags": null,
  "type": "Microsoft.ContainerService/ContainerServices",
  "windowsProfile": null
}
```

We can use PowerShell to get the service principal:

```
PS C:\Users> Get-AzureRmADServicePrincipal | ?{ $_.ApplicationId -eq "1498b171-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-8ef56a178b89" } | fl *


ServicePrincipalNames : {http://azure-cli-2017-04-13-08-16-07, 1498b171-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-8ef56a178b89}
ApplicationId         : 1498b171-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-8ef56a178b89
DisplayName           : azure-cli-2017-04-13-08-16-07
Id                    : d86886b9-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-25ab57803a33
Type                  : ServicePrincipal
```

Comment: Hey I managed to fix it by creating the cluster through Azure CLI. And letting it generate the SP on it's own. Thank you for your great response though!